# CoreData Fetch Where All Relationship Property is True

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have two NSManagedObjects as described below.

```
extension Day {
    @NSManaged var date: NSDate?
    @NSManaged var isHighPriority: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var projects: NSSet?
}

extension Project {
    @NSManaged var complete: Bool
    @NSManaged var title: String?
    @NSManaged var day: Day?
}
```

What I want to do is fetch all `Day` objects where all the `Projects` are completed. However, when I attempt this fetch request I'm getting this error. `Exception was caught during NSPersistentStoreCoordinator -performBlock: Unsupported predicate`

Here is my predicate

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isHighPriority == %@ AND ALL projects.complete == TRUE", NSNumber(bool: true))
```

How do I properly fetch all `Day`s where every `Project` in the set has been completed? I could fetch and then `filter` but I'd rather do it all at the CoreData level.

Comment: I don't exacly know about Swift's modifications to NSPredicate syntax, but shouldn't it be `YES` instead of `TRUE`?

Comment: Produces the same result. It's invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to perform this by doing a `SUBQUERY` in the `NSPredicate`

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isHighPriority == %@ AND SUBQUERY(projects, $project, $project.complete == TRUE).@count == projects.@count", NSNumber(bool: true))
```